# Is there any API (official or otherwise) to work with the Google Places for Business Dashboard?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working with a client that has a lot (high 3-digit number) of business listings. Is there any way to access the information that Google provides via the Places Dashboard with an API?

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't provide an API. We do have a large merchant interface for companies that are chains or franchises.